# Jquery reordering list not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile

I have a list that I'd like to reorder with jquery. This works fine on desktop but on mobile (iphone) it doesn't do the reordering. This is my code:

```
<div class="quick-action-list">
    <a class="alpha">Sort A to Z</a> <a class="alpha_reverse" style="display:none;">Sort Z to A</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a title="A" href="">A</a></li>
    <li><a title="B" href="">B</a></li>
    <li><a title="C" href="">C</a></li>
    <li><a title="D" href="">D</a></li>
    <li><a title="E" href="">E</a></li>
    <li><a title="F" href="">F</a></li>
    <li><a title="G" href="">G</a></li>
    <li><a title="H" href="">H</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

my jquery:

```
$('.quick-action-list .alpha').on('click', function () {
        var $actions = $(this).closest(".quick-action-list").find("ul li");
        var alphabeticallyOrderedActions = $actions.sort(function (c, d) {
            return $(c).find("a").text() > $(d).find("a").text();
        });
        $(this).closest(".quick-action-list").find("ul").html(alphabeticallyOrderedActions);
        $(this).closest(".quick-action-list").find('.alpha_reverse').show();
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $('.quick-action-list .alpha_reverse').on('click', function () {
        var $actions = $(this).closest(".quick-action-list").find("ul li");
        var alphabeticallyOrderedActions = $actions.sort(function (c, d) {
            return $(c).find("a").text() < $(d).find("a").text();
        });
        $(this).closest(".quick-action-list").find("ul").html(alphabeticallyOrderedActions);
        $(this).closest(".quick-action-list").find('.alpha').show();
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

Instead of click I tried `('click touchstart')` or just `('touchstart')` but this doesn't work either. It toggles the `<a>` alright but it doesn't reorder the list.

Here's the code in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/06e4g53h/1/

My question is, why is touchstart (or click) toggling the link but not actually reordering the list? Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use Javascript's .sort() function correctly. It should return integers rather than true/false.

Instead of

```
var alphabeticallyOrderedActions = $actions.sort(function (c, d) {
  return $(c).find("a").text() < $(d).find("a").text();
});
```

try

```
var alphabeticallyOrderedActions = $actions.sort(function (c, d) {
  return $(c).find("a").text() < $(d).find("a").text() ? -1 : $(c).find("a").text() > $(d).find("a").text() ? 1 : 0;
});
```

See updated fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/06e4g53h/3/

Comment: Thank you. What I don't understand that it works on desktop. I didn't get an error with this javascript so assumed it was correct.

Comment: Javascript compilers differ. Sometimes compilers are handling wrong code gracefully. You can only be assured that your app works on all plattforms if you stick to the standards. I agree, this one was difficult to realize here.